# Geary email client how can I make it a dark theme

Tags: email-client, geary

As the title suggest I really like the looks of geary and the smaller memory footprint vs thunderbird but where is the dark theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jaraj Fiala for this answer:

> sure, you can either change your GTK+ theme to a dark theme like
>   Adwaita-dark, or launch Geary with:

```
   env GTK_THEME=Adwaita-dark org.gnome.Geary
```

in my case with Linux Mint Cinnamon 18.3 I use ( 
       `env GTK_THEME=Adwaita-dark geary` )

or, if you are using the Flatpak version (can recommend):

```
   flatpak run --env=GTK_THEME=Adwaita-dark org.gnome.Geary
```

turns out you can set the GTK_THEME for other apps as well using the env flag!!

Answer (score 1):

Geary 0.12 and later uses whichever GTK+3 theme your desktop environment has been configured to use, so if you want Geary to use a dark theme you'll need to configure your desktop's settings to enable that.

There is some support for customising the CSS used to display individual messages in a conversation, see the [Geary FAQ](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Geary/FAQ#Under_the_Hood) for details. This does not currently apply to the Composer at the moment, but there is an [open ticket](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=714129) requesting that.

Comment: I'm using a dark theme with Linux mint cinnamon and that doesn't propogate to Geary.  I was able to change the css files I found then recompile and it is now dark theme except for the message pane which is still white.

Comment: Oh, if you're on Mint you'll need to make sure you're running at least Geary 0.12 for it to pick up the dark theme completely. You can install the latest version from the [official PPA](https://launchpad.net/~geary-team/+archive/ubuntu/releases).

Comment: I'm running Geary 0.12.1, I also have use dark theme varient when available in theme settings turned on.  @MichaelGatton is there a git folder to submit a branch, I know having a dark theme is important to a lot of people.  I am also looking for a way to just show unread email like I can do in thunderbird...

Comment: @flyingdrifter, Geary's source code and bugs are hosted on GNOME's infrastructure, you can find links to it on the [Contribute](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Geary/Contribute) page.